# How to show the SQLite dataset in the activity, and update inside?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

[Book Library Link](https://github.com/stevdza-san/SQLite_Android-Complete_Tutorial)

Currently, I am creating a note application with reference to the above link, but when I move from MainActivity to UpdateAcitivity, the content of the note I should have clicked is not displayed

Since the data is displayed in MainActivity, there is no problem in saving the data itself. However, the reason why the data is not displayed in UpdateActivity is that the withdrawal from the DB has failed. not. Please help.

[image: MainActivity]

[image: UpdateActivity]

```js
UpdateActivity

package com.example.noteapp;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class UpdateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText title_input;
    Button update_button, delete_button;

    //↓What I Add
    MultiAutoCompleteTextView message_input;
    //MultiAutoCompleteTextView message_input = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.me);

    String id, title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);

        title_input = findViewById(R.id.title_input2);
        update_button = findViewById(R.id.ub);
        delete_button = findViewById(R.id.db);

        //↓What I add
        message_input = findViewById(R.id.me);

        //First we call this
        getAndSetIntentData();

        //Set actionbar title after getAndSetIntentData method
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setTitle(title);
        }

        update_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //And only then we call this
                MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(UpdateActivity.this);
                title = title_input.getText().toString().trim();
                String message = message_input.getText().toString().trim();
                myDB.updateData(id, title, message);
            }
        });
        delete_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                confirmDialog();
            }
        });

    }

    void getAndSetIntentData(){
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("id") && getIntent().hasExtra("title") && getIntent().hasExtra("message")){
            //Getting Data from Intent
            id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
            String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

            //Setting Intent Data
            title_input.setText(title);
            message_input.setText(message);
            Log.d("stev", title);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "No data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void confirmDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Delete " + title + " ?");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete " + title + " ?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(UpdateActivity.this);
                myDB.deleteOneRow(id);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

```html
activity_updateXML

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="30dp"
    tools:context=".UpdateActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title_input2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.266"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <MultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/me"
        android:layout_width="355dp"
        android:layout_height="148dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Message"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_input2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Update"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="321dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/db"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.483"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="421dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```js
MyDatabaseHelper

package com.example.noteapp;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private Context context;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "note.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "my_note";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE = "message";

    MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_MESSAGE + " TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    void addNote(String title, String message){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, message);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    Cursor readAllData(){
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = null;
        if(db != null){
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        }
        return cursor;
    }

    void updateData(String row_id, String title, String message){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_TITLE, title);
        cv.put(COLUMN_MESSAGE, message);

        long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Updated Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    void deleteOneRow(String row_id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        long result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
        if(result == -1){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    void deleteAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
    }

}
```

```js
MainActivity

package com.example.noteapp;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    FloatingActionButton add_button;
    ImageView empty_imageview;
    TextView no_data;

    MyDatabaseHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<String> note_id, note_title, note_message;
    //CustomAdapter customAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        add_button = findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        empty_imageview = findViewById(R.id.empty_imageview);
        no_data = findViewById(R.id.no_data);
        add_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InsertActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
        note_id = new ArrayList<>();
        note_title = new ArrayList<>();
        note_message = new ArrayList<>();

        storeDataInArrays();

        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, this, note_id, note_title, note_message);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1){
            recreate();
        }
    }

    void storeDataInArrays(){
        Cursor cursor = myDB.readAllData();
        if(cursor.getCount() == 0){
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else{
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
                note_id.add(cursor.getString(0));
                note_title.add(cursor.getString(1));
                note_message.add(cursor.getString(2));
            }
            empty_imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            no_data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == R.id.delete_all){
            confirmDialog();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    void confirmDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Delete All?");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete all Data?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
                myDB.deleteAllData();
                //Refresh Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
    }
}
```

================CustomeAdapter====================

```js
CustomeAdapter

package com.example.noteapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList note_id, note_title, note_message;

    CustomAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, ArrayList note_id, ArrayList note_title, ArrayList note_message){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.note_id = note_id;
        this.note_title = note_title;
        this.note_message = note_message;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.note_id_txt.setText(String.valueOf(note_id.get(position)));
        holder.note_title_txt.setText(String.valueOf(note_title.get(position)));
        holder.note_message_txt.setText(String.valueOf(note_message.get(position)));
        //Recyclerview onClickListener
        holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(note_id.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("title", String.valueOf(note_title.get(position)));
                intent.putExtra("author", String.valueOf(note_message.get(position)));
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return note_id.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView note_id_txt, note_title_txt, note_message_txt;
        LinearLayout mainLayout;

        MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            note_id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_id_txt);
            note_title_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title_txt);
            note_message_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_message_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            //Animate Recyclerview
            Animation translate_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_anim);
            mainLayout.setAnimation(translate_anim);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I saw your code, its seems there is no problem ... can you share the MainActivity.class ... I think there are problem in sending data not in getting

Comment: Thanks, I add MainActivity.

Comment: I think I have a similar implementation in one of my Github project that you might check - https://github.com/masudias/SqliteDBReadWriteUpdate

Comment: It looks like you are not passing the intent extras correctly while launching the `UpdateActivity` from your `CustomAdapter`. Can you please share the code of your `CustomAdapter` so that we could take a look? Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again, I hadn't had that perspective, I added CustomAdapter.

Comment: Looks like everything is in order. I really do not see the problem other than the data is not being loaded into the array lists correctly. Can you please put logs in your code and verify if the data are stored in the `ArrayList`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem in the CustomeAdapter exactly in **onBindViewHolder**.
replace this code from onBindViewHolder:

```
 holder.mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", holder.note_id_txt.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("title",holder.note_title_txt.getText().toString()  );
                intent.putExtra("author", holder.note_message_txt.getText().toString());
                activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
        });
```

and put this inside your viewHolder class:

```
MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            note_id_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_id_txt);
            note_title_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_title_txt);
            note_message_txt = itemView.findViewById(R.id.note_message_txt);
            mainLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            //Animate Recyclerview
            Animation translate_anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.translate_anim);
            mainLayout.setAnimation(translate_anim);

mainLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", note_id_txt.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("title",note_title_txt.getText().toString()  );
                    intent.putExtra("author",   note_message_txt.getText().toString());
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed. Here is my all code https://github.com/Kazukafka/NoteApp

Comment: in all my project I put the set OnClickListenet inside ViewHolder Class... I will modify my previous comment

Comment: No just move the code to your inner class "MyViewHolder" inside CustomAdapter ... you've already created this inner class

Comment: Well, my apologies, nothing changed. Maybe my android studio itself issue? https://github.com/Kazukafka/NoteApp

Comment: I'm curious because I resee your code and there is not an error... if you add some Logs UpdateActivity exactly in getAndSetIntentData() and see what getIntent return by this way we can know which classes are work correctly and which are not

Comment: If it works on your Emulator, it would be fine, however, I got  an error after I restart my android studio then, that would like→Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'UNKNOWN'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213808/discussion-between-kazy-and-akram-bensalem).